# How to avoid that .click() adds new listeners every time it is used

Tags: jquery, events

I have function which adds event listeners (.click(...)) to some elements (among many other tasks).

**I need to call this function multiple times** (for example on window resize). 
Each time I call this function the listeners are added again - so if I call my function 3 times, each click will fire 3 times instead of one time.

I have build a simplyfied example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5NmIruVoAknfcrRTBSYb

```
  var clickMe = $("#clickme");
  function init() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickMe.click(function() {
        $("#output").append(".");
      })
    }, 100)
  }

  init();

  $("#recall").click(function() {
    init();
  });
```

Of course this sample (and the setTimeout) does not make sense, but it reflects my code block best.
Is it possible to closure the whole init function in a way that the everything is reset if I call it? Or do I have to remove the events with unbind() every time?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. Insert `
      clickMe.unbind( "click" );` Before `clickMe.click(function()` Like this https://plnkr.co/edit/iFAEantGoMyIhkYJMKwj?p=preview

Comment: if you are using `Jquery` with version greater than 1.7, it would be better to use `on` `off` rather than `unbind`

Comment: This works, Carsten, but I hope there's a more elegant solution, because I have many elements/handlers.

Comment: You can use 'e.stopPropogation();' for recall click function

Comment: It sounds like you need to use event delegation instead of this rather hacky solution

Comment: @Rory - can you show me? - clickMe.on('click', (...)) doesn't help.

Comment: Replace all of the above with `$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function() { $("#output").append("."); });`

Comment: If someone wants to put Rory's comment into an answer, this would be my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your code and I think this is a fix

If you Remove the click event

```
.off("click")
```

then you can add it back in again, this will always remove it if it exists before adding it.

```
.off("click").on("click", function() {
```

The following is the changed javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
  var clickMe = $("#clickme");
  function init() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickMe.off("click").on("click", function() {
      $("#output").append(".");
      })
    }, 100)
   }
 $("#recall").click(function() {
   init();
 }); 
})
```

Comment: Yeah it is a bit of a Hack, If I spot a cleaner way of doing it, I will update my answer :)